# Automated Drip/ WorkFlow Form using a Plugin for WordPress site, or using a 3rd party

Tags: wordpress, plugins, workflow

I have a challenge.. and wish I was able to resolve it by posting it here.

I wish to create a Form using a WordPress plugin or 3rd party embedded form to my WordPress site, that when a visitor/ customer/ prospect submits the info, a pop-up displays a user and password info (automated), **OR** deliver automatically an email/ SMS to the subscriber with the login/ password info. And this flow wilL stop/ end/ conclude **after** the first 20 submissions. I would like this to be all automated.

On the other side, I will create 20 login/ passwords manually at the platform. So the submitter can enter it on the home page and access the platform. Do you know of any plugins, or 3rd party services that can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear if the credentials you are wiling to generate and show are from WordPress itself or a 3rd party application. If your question is specific to WordPress maybe you can ask it at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ Also, it is not clear how Drip/ Workflow Form you mention on the title relates to it. Overall, your requirements might be too narrow to any available plugin to be able to comply with exactly that specific workflow. Other than that, please be careful when exposing pre-generated credentials to avoid eventual unintended harmful activities.

Comment: The Credentials are created manually and will be sent to the subscriber, after submitting the form. I will create the user logins manually myself.